# Why doesn't the People Pane in Outlook 2010 show appointments for individual contacts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, contacts, appointments

Outlook 2010 will not show appointments in the people pane. Under the activities tab if I go to All Items then eventually the appointments will show, but this takes a seriously long time. If I then click off the tab to look at another field then return to All Items, all the appointments are gone again.

I need to be able to:

- Open a contact and see when that contact has appointments
- Open an appointment and see which contacts are attached to that appointment

It works well from the appointment card to the contact, but has me completely frustrated going from the contact card to find the appontments. I have tried many things but cannot solve this problem. My set up is as follows:

- Exchange Server
- Windows 7 Ultimate
- Indexing enabled
- Cached exchange mode enabled

Help! This is the whole reason I installed Outlook 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Three things worth trying:

1. Go to the following key in the registry:

   ```
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\Outlook\SocialConnector
   ```

   If you can't see a string value called `RunOSC` then create one with a value of 1.
2. If that makes no difference then look for a DWORD value called `PeoplePaneModeExplorer` and set the value of it to 1.
3. Finally you can try temporarily disabling the cached exchange mode, then re-enable it.